# In Cura remove Top/Bottom on overhang

Tags: ultimaker-cura

Is there a way to get rid of the (yellow) internal support, Cura is generating for overhangs?

[image: Top/Bottom on Overhang from top]
[image: Top/Bottom on Overhang from side]

I am already printing with 3 walls, so there should be no additional benefit in this case and it is harming my print.

(Reason: I want to print this in silk PLA, which is very temperature sensitive. These overhangs tend to curl up, due to the additional material and heating. Adding more part cooling will hurt the layer adhesion dramatically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Skin Removal Width** should be the setting you are looking for.

[image]

PrusaSlicer's equivalent is **[Ensure vertical shell thickness](https://help.prusa3d.com/article/layers-and-perimeters_1748#ensure-vertical-shell-thickness)**.

Comment: Found it for PrusiaSlicer but not the equivalent in Cura. Tank you!

I do not Understand why I have to set it to 3 mm for this Model but at least it seems to do what I need.